# QGIS C++ Custom Point Feature label Placement

Tags: qgis, c++

I am using QGIS and C++for secondary development, and I want to customize the method of placing point feature labels. Based on mathematical rules, I will re select candidate label positions for point features, which is to extend the 'Placement' of the QgsPalLayerSettings class.
[image]
The presentation of labels in mapCanvas requires a lot of functions, but what confuses me now is that I cannot fully understand the label placement engine of QGIS,

Perhaps I should inherit some interface classes,
such as class MLabelProvider: public QgsAbstractLabelProvider,
[image]
and define personalized label placement methods within the class, but I don't know what to do next...Ask for help.